# Need to duplicate a Modal I created but I am not sure what attributes need to be changed in order to do so? Need to duplicate it 3 times

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, modal-dialog

This modal works perfectly, I now need to duplicate this exact modal 3 times on the same page. I need 3 separate buttons on the same page, to be able to call 3 separate modals. Right now I do not know what attributes need to be changed in order for me to achieve this.

This is the code within the body (CTA Button)

```
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button id="modal-btn" class="button"> LEARN MORE</button>
```

This is the code for the Modal...

```
<!-- JQUERY SCRIPT -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- BEGIN CSS STYLES -->
<style>
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed; 
  padding-top: 50px;
  left: 0; 
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: white;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  overflow: scroll;
}
.modal-content {
  position: relative; 
  padding: 10px; 
  margin: auto; 
  width: 75%;  
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
}
.close-btn {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 50px; 
  color: lightgray; 
  font-size: 24px;  
  font-weight: bold;
}
.close-btn:hover {
  color: darkgray;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
  to {top:0; opacity:1}
}
@keyframes animatetop {
  from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
  to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

.button {
  background-color: #04347b; /* Blue */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 80px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}
</style>
<!-- END CSS STYLES -->

<!-- BEGIN MODAL -->
<div class="modal">
<div class="modal-header">
    <span class="close-btn">&times;</span>
  </div>
  
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12" style="background-color: white; padding: 25px 50px;">
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12"><h2>Physiotherapy</h2></div>
<!--PRODUCT 1-->
<div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2" style="padding:10px 0;"><img src="{{media url=wysiwyg/images-test-1.png}}" alt="" /></div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4" style="padding:10px 0; text-align: left;">
<p><strong>PRODUCT TITLE 1<br>
Ref: xxxxxxx</strong></p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<!--END PRODUCT 1-->

<!--PRODUCT 2-->
<div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2" style="padding:10px 0;"><img src="{{media url=wysiwyg/images-test-1.png}}" alt="" /></div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4" style="padding:10px 0; text-align: left;">
<p><strong>PRODUCT TITLE 2<br>
Ref: xxxxxxx</strong></p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<!--END PRODUCT 2-->
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12" style="background-color: white; padding: 25px 50px;">
<!--PRODUCT 3-->
<div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2" style="padding:10px 0;"><img src="{{media url=wysiwyg/images-test-1.png}}" alt="" /></div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4" style="padding:10px 0; text-align: left;">
<p><strong>PRODUCT TITLE 3<br>
Ref: xxxxxxx</strong></p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<!--END PRODUCT 3-->

<!--PRODUCT 4-->
<div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2" style="padding:10px 0;"><img src="{{media url=wysiwyg/images-test-1.png}}" alt="" /></div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4" style="padding:10px 0; text-align: left;">
<p><strong>PRODUCT TITLE 4<br>
Ref: xxxxxxx</strong></p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<!--END PRODUCT 4-->
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12" style="background-color: white; padding: 25px 50px;">
<!--PRODUCT 5-->
<div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2" style="padding:10px 0;"><img src="{{media url=wysiwyg/images-test-1.png}}" alt="" /></div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4" style="padding:10px 0; text-align: left;">
<p><strong>PRODUCT TITLE 5<br>
Ref: xxxxxxx</strong></p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<!--END PRODUCT 5-->

<!--PRODUCT 6-->
<div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2" style="padding:10px 0;"><img src="{{media url=wysiwyg/images-test-1.png}}" alt="" /></div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4" style="padding:10px 0; text-align: left;">
<p><strong>PRODUCT TITLE 6<br>
Ref: xxxxxxx</strong></p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<!--END PRODUCT 6-->
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12" style="background-color: white; padding: 25px 50px;">
<!--PRODUCT 7-->
<div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2" style="padding:10px 0;"><img src="{{media url=wysiwyg/images-test-1.png}}" alt="" /></div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4" style="padding:10px 0; text-align: left;">
<p><strong>PRODUCT TITLE 7<br>
Ref: xxxxxxx</strong></p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<!--END PRODUCT 7-->

<!--PRODUCT 8-->
<div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2" style="padding:10px 0;"><img src="{{media url=wysiwyg/images-test-1.png}}" alt="" /></div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4" style="padding:10px 0; text-align: left;">
<p><strong>PRODUCT TITLE 8<br>
Ref: xxxxxxx</strong></p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<!--END PRODUCT 8-->
</div>

</div>
</div>
<!-- END MODAL -->

<!-- BEGIN SCRIPT -->
<script type="text/javascript">
let modalBtn = document.getElementById("modal-btn")
let modal = document.querySelector(".modal")
let closeBtn = document.querySelector(".close-btn")
modalBtn.onclick = function(){
  modal.style.display = "block"
}
closeBtn.onclick = function(){
  modal.style.display = "none"
}
window.onclick = function(e){
  if(e.target == modal){
    modal.style.display = "none"
  }
}
</script>
<!-- END SCRIPT -->

<!-- BEGIN SCRIPT -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.modal').click(function(){
  $('.modal').show();
  $('body').css("overflow", "hidden");
});
</script>
<!-- END SCRIPT -->
```

Comment: This: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

Answer (score 0):

you can store the contents in hidden div. like this:

```
<div class="modal-hidden-content-1" style="display:none">CONTENT 1</div>
<div class="modal-hidden-content-2" style="display:none">CONTENT 2</div>
<div class="modal-hidden-content-3" style="display:none">CONTENT 3</div>
```

your modal div:

```
<div class="modal">
<div class="modal-header">
    <span class="close-btn">&times;</span>
</div>
<div class="modal-content"></div>
</div>
```

and buttons:

```
<button onclick="openModal('1')" class="button"> LEARN MORE 1</button>
<button onclick="openModal('2')" class="button"> LEARN MORE 2</button>
<button onclick="openModal('3')" class="button"> LEARN MORE 3</button>
```

and then javascript must be :

```
<script>
function openModal(i) {
  $('.modal-content').html($('.modal-hidden-content-'+i).html())
  $('.modal').show();
  $('body').css("overflow", "hidden");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Hakan for your help, you are really helping me out of a bind :) I'm not that strong with code so I hope I understood you correctly. I wasn't sure where to put the hidden divs code within my code, if you could let me know I would really appreciate it, thank you so much :)

Comment: Hi Walter, you can put div's where you want. i suggest in <body></body> tags